# how can I accommodate the doi content within text height area on first page for two column layout

Tags: footnotes, two-column

This is my first question in this forum.

While creating a two column layout, I'm trying to place DOI content (spanned to both columns) at the bottom of first page and falling within the text height (Not in footer area).

I've placed as footnote in `\maketitle`. But is clashing with right column content. I don't want to disturb the the TeX file and this needs to be handled only through sty/cls files.

```
\def\maketitle{%
\twocolumn[\finalMaketitle]\printFirstPageNotes
\gdef\thefootnote{\arabic{footnote}}
\footnotetext{\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}[t]{@{}p{\textwidth}@{}}
http://xx.doi.org/00.0000/a.aaaa.2017.02.016\newline
0000-0000/\copyright 2017 Journal Name. Published Name. All rights reserved.
\end{tabular*}}
}
```

Here is my output view:

[image]

Can anybody help me to handle this through sty/cls files.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Answer (score 2):

Why do you need tabular here?  And why would you want manual breaks in doi url?

Try

```
\footnotetext{\url{https://doi.org/00.0000/a.aaaa.2017.02.0160000-0000/ \textcopyright~2017 Journal Name. Published Name. All rights reserved.}
```

You need hyperref package to get urls in footnotes.  Also, note the new standard of DOI formatting (https://doi.org/...)

If you want your copyright strip to span both columns, do not use footnotes.  Rather, use fancyhdr, and put it as the footer on the first page using a separate page style for the first page of output.

**Update** if you want the copyright strip in the body text area:

1. Decrease the body text height on the first page using `\enlargethispage` with negative amount.
2. Raise the footer on the first page using, for example, `\raisebox`

Comment: I want the DOI strip to span both columns and it is to be placed within page body area (i.e. the base of DOI strip to align with bottom  most line of next page.

Comment: please see update